# Chromium doesn't open file dialog

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, xdg

When using chromium, the open or save file dialogs don't work. Examples: attaching a file or trying to download the attachment. I click them, nothing happens, nothing pops up. When running Firefox, everything works.

It was working until probably the last system upgrade. I'm running Arch with i3.

I've run chromium with verbose logging and when I click on "upload file dialog" (for example in Outlook), this is what I see:

```
[5251:5268:0920/121205.644743:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(919)] Method call: message_type: MESSAGE_METHOD_CALL
interface: org.freedesktop.DBus
member: GetNameOwner
signature: s

string "org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop"

[5251:5268:0920/121205.648047:VERBOSE1:object_proxy.cc(513)] Signal received: message_type: MESSAGE_SIGNAL
destination: :1.28
path: /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop/request/1_28/handle_1
interface: org.freedesktop.portal.Request
member: Response
sender: :1.12
signature: ua{sv}
serial: 564

uint32_t 2
array [
  dict entry {
    string "uris"
    variant       array [
      ]
  }
]

[5251:5268:0920/121206.022392:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(919)] Method call: message_type: MESSAGE_METHOD_CALL
interface: org.freedesktop.DBus
member: GetNameOwner
signature: s

string "org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop"

[5251:5268:0920/121206.025171:VERBOSE1:object_proxy.cc(513)] Signal received: message_type: MESSAGE_SIGNAL
destination: :1.28
path: /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop/request/1_28/handle_2
interface: org.freedesktop.portal.Request
member: Response
sender: :1.12
signature: ua{sv}
serial: 574

uint32_t 2
array [
  dict entry {
    string "uris"
    variant       array [
      ]
  }
]

[5251:5268:0920/121206.182218:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(919)] Method call: message_type: MESSAGE_METHOD_CALL
interface: org.freedesktop.DBus
member: GetNameOwner
signature: s

string "org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop"

[5251:5268:0920/121206.184384:VERBOSE1:object_proxy.cc(513)] Signal received: message_type: MESSAGE_SIGNAL
destination: :1.28
path: /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop/request/1_28/handle_3
interface: org.freedesktop.portal.Request
member: Response
sender: :1.12
signature: ua{sv}
serial: 584

uint32_t 2
array [
  dict entry {
    string "uris"
    variant       array [
      ]
  }
]
```

(here I clicked it 3 times).

Okay, so what do I do? The only thing that comes to mind is I changed the default theme (so Chromium and other apps would use it) like this:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/color-scheme \'prefer-dark\'
```

but as I remember, the file dialogs were working since then. It's only recently that it stopped working.

And by the way:

```
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

(Firefox seems to use it)

Do you guys know what can I do to fix it?

P.S Already performed the system upgrade and rebooted - didn't help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It seems I have the [same issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772262/no-file-open-save-as-dialogue-in-chrome-brave) with i3/Chrome.

Comment: Yeah. I don't remember exactly, but I installed packages like `xdg-desktop-portal` and `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` . This + some package upgrades and I got it working. But I don't know which one was it...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the console output that you posted, it seems like you're missing the xdg desktop portal. I don't use arch, but, based on the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Desktop_Portal), it seems like you have to install the `xdg-desktop-portal` package, and a backend package of your choice, for example `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`.