# No "File Open" / "Save As" dialogue in Chrome/Brave

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, i3, desktop, xdg

I have a strange behaviour in my Chrome-based browsers.

I cannot open/upload/save/download files. It does not show me the "file open" dialogue when I press an upload button on any website. Also, manually hitting CTRL+S or CTRL+O does not show me any dialogue.

Here is my system:

- Archlinux `Linux 6.7.0-arch3-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Google Chrome `google-chrome 122.0.6261.128-1`
- Brave `brave-bin 1:1.63.169-1`

I'm using an `i3` desktop environment. I use the same config for the desktop across different laptops and workstations and only have issues on this one machine.

Also, I *can* open/save files on other browsers like Firefox. I'm not sure what the issue is with Chrome based browsers. Restarting or resetting them also does not help at all.

```
~
❯ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
caja-folder-handler.desktop
```

I did some research and learned that these file dialogues live in [`xdg-desktop-portal`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Desktop_Portal).

I tried multiple backends but none seems to help with the issue at hand:

```
~
❯ pacman -Qs xdg-desktop     
local/xdg-desktop-portal 1.18.2-1
    Desktop integration portals for sandboxed apps
local/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome 45.1-1 (gnome)
    A backend implementation for xdg-desktop-portal for the GNOME desktop environment
local/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk 1.15.1-1
    A backend implementation for xdg-desktop-portal using GTK
local/xdg-desktop-portal-xapp 1.0.4-1
    A backend implementation for xdg-desktop-portal using GTK and various pieces of Cinnamon/MATE/Xfce4 infrastructure
```

What else can I try?

Comment: Type `chrome://settings/downloads` in the Address Bar. Is `Ask where to save each file before downloading` On or Off?

Comment: It's turned on.

Comment: Are you running the MATE desktop environment?